# Как можно присвоить значение которое вводит пользователь значению атрибута?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Имеем фрагмент JavaScript:

```
order: {
                    amount: 500,
                    currency: "BYN",
                    description: "Payment description",
                    tracking_id: "my_transaction_id"
                },
```

В нем внимание на значение `amount: 500`, ниже мы к нему вернемся.

Так же, **на этой же странице** имеется фрагмент кода, который выводит строчку для ввода числового значения руками пользователя:

```
<input type="number" id="variable" value="35" min="35" max="40" step="1">
```

Каким образом, можно передать числовые значения которые вводит пользователь, в значение `amount: 500`, то что в JS на этой же странице?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: обработайте событие `onclick`  или `onchange`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
order: {
                amount: document.getElementById('variable').value,
                currency: "BYN",
                description: "Payment description",
                tracking_id: "my_transaction_id"
            },
```